# ios - Passing on data to another method - same viewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, methods, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Please see this code as an example:

```
-(void)generateConnection
{

    NSString *urlString = @"";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    NSLog(@"%@", connection);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString *partialData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [_jsonContentForText appendString:partialData];

    NSLog(@"%@", partialData);
}
```

Really for lack knowing what it is called, but after searching - a lot - I am unable to out what this process is called.

I need to know how `-(void)connection:` gets the information it needs from the previous method. I don't know if this is called passing on methods to another method, but I need to create another one, so I need to know where I can learn this.

Please spare me the lines like: You need to read up on objective-c and the general stuff, because those answers do not cover the specific need I have.

I do not mind reading up on it, as long as I know what I am reading explains this. However if in any kind hearts it is easy to explain, I will not reject that offer:-)

Comment: When you create a connection object, you are setting the delegate to self. "[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];". This is what tells the system, that for all the call back methods, use the current object and call the methods in the current object. self means current object. Not only this method, but all the delegate methods of connection object are called on the current object. Please read about Delegates in ios and you will know what is happening.

Comment: So going by that, I can only create a single NSURLConnection per ViewController?? that is ok as long as I get that - I mean the way I understand it, is that I cannot distinguish between the following methods, because they are based on the delegate - which is self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read up on Delegates and Protocols. When you create the `NSURLConnection` and set `self` as the delegate, your new `NSURLConnection` object is told to query `self` (the object that created it) to do things like find out if authentication is supported, or what to do when it receives some data. For the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` specifically, if your delegate implements the methods defined in [NSURLConnectionDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), they'll be called.

Some good sources to read up on Delegates and Protocols are:

- [Working with Protocols(Apple)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html)
- [Delegates and Data Sources(Apple)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html)
- [The Basics of Protocols and Delegates(Mobile Developer Tips)](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html)

Comment: thanks - I knew reading was involved, so I will get right to it:-)

Comment: On the question about supporting multiple connections - yes, it's completely possible. Well designed `Protocols` support passing in the calling object as a parameter to the delegate method. You can use that to determine which specific connection (lets say you had an array of them) was making the call. Good luck!